# Javascript: attach child several deep to object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

If I want to iterate through a list like this:

```
var inputArray = [
    'CHILD0',
    'PARENT0_CHILD1',
    'PARENT1_PARENT2_CHILD2',
    'PARENT1_PARENT3_CHILD3',
    'PARENT1_PARENT3_CHILD4'
];
```

And have it return an object like so:

```
var resultObject = {
    CHILD0: null,
    PARENT0: {CHILD1: null},
    PARENT1: {
        PARENT2: {CHILD2: null},
        PARENT3: {
            CHILD3: null,
            CHILD4: null    
        }
    }
};
```

How could I iterate through the array to return the result?

I've got something like this:

```
function iterateArray (inputArray) {
  var _RESULT = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i += 1) {
    var _inputName = inputArray[i];
    var _inputNameArray = _input.split('_');
    var _ref;

    for (var n = 0; n < _inputNameArray.length; n += 1) {
      //...?
    }

    _RESULT[_ref] = null;
  }

  return _RESULT;
}

var resultObject = iterateArray(inputArray);
```

Not sure what to do from this point. Think I might need a recursive function of sorts. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes use a recursive function which take: the element in which you add the property, the array splitted, the id of the value to insert in the array.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant, thanks that did help me conceptualize how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With minimal changes to your code:

```
function iterateArray (inputArray) {
  var _RESULT = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i += 1) {
    var _inputName = inputArray[i];
    var _inputNameArray = _inputName.split('_');
    var _ref = _RESULT;

    for (var n = 0; n < _inputNameArray.length - 1; n += 1) {
      if (!_ref[_inputNameArray[n]]) _ref[_inputNameArray[n]] = {};
      _ref = _ref[_inputNameArray[n]];
    }

    _ref[_inputNameArray[n]] = null;
  }

  return _RESULT;
}
```

You never *need* recursion, as it can always be unwrapped into iteration (and vice versa). Things are just sometimes much nicer one way or another.

EDIT: What's with all the underscores? :)

EDIT2: The key point to understanding this is reference sharing. For example:

- For `CHILD0`, `_ref = _RESULT` means both of the variables are pointing at the *same `{}`*. When you do `_ref['CHILD0'] = null`, it is the same as doing `_RESULT['CHILD0'] = null`.
- For `PARENT0_CHILD1`, first `_ref = _RESULT` as above, so `_ref['PARENT0'] = {}` is the same as `_RESULT['PARENT0'] = {}`. Then we switch the meaning of `_ref` to be the same thing as `_RESULT['PARENT0']`; when we assign `_ref['CHILD1'] = null`, it is the same as assigning `_RESULT['PARENT0']['CHILD1'] = null`.

Comment: Amadan, thanks, this works. How...? I'm not too sure. There is some black magic around how the reference iterates through the `_RESULT` array, which I don't understand too well. Somehow `_RESULT` is updating each time you append a new object onto `_ref`. But I don't understand how you are working your way downward the `_ref` object, and updating the original object, simultaneously.

Comment: Added more in-depth explanation. Does it make more sense now?